# Unable to remove postfix on Ubuntu: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'exim4'

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, exim

I'm trying to remove postfix from my (recently upgraded to 10.10) Ubuntu server.

I keep getting this error when I try to remove it (with `apt-get remove postfix`, or `purge`):

> Could not perform immediate configuration on `'exim4'`.Please see `man 5 apt.conf` under `APT::Immediate-Configure` for details. (2)

exim4 is not installed.

Comment: Installing sendmail fixed the problem...

Comment: If you don't need the overhead, it's better to install a smaller thing like sSMTP.

Answer (score 1):

Your system should have some mailing system. So you can't just delete the last email system.
Try to install exim4 first and then remove postfix.

Or use `apt-get install -f or dpkg-reconfigure exim4`.